# .htaccess url rewrite not working witouth trailing slash?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the URL of a page in my website. Its basicly really simple. My original URL looks like this

http://www.mypage.com/website/page.php?slug=my-page

I want it to look like this: http://wwww.mypage.com/website/my-page/

And that works. What doesent work is if you remove the trailing slash. This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

It seems as if i remove the slash the $_GET['slug'] becomes only page.php but with a trailing slash the variable says "my-page".

Is it possible to make it so the link works both without and with trailing slash?

***Edit:*** Does it matter if i have the .htaccess and php file in a childfolder? So my real url is like this: http://www.mypage.com/website/page.php?slug=something

I've now edited the post with how it really is.

Comment: The location of the htaccess file makes a difference. Look up how htaccess works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
RewriteRule ^website/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ website/page.php?slug=$1      [NC,L,QSA]
```

Amend the regex as needed depending on the type of URLs you want to accept.

Look up how htaccess works with regard to things like querystrings and so on:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: @jaypCheck your code - you have an open paren and a closing square bracket atm!

Comment: Tried it again but didn't work, now i get a 404 not found. But look at my original post, i've updated it with some info. You see im not in the root folder of the domain. Does that effect anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

The question mark makes the trailing slash optional. I would also suggest to have only one kind of URLs. Like redirect URLs without the trailing salsh, to the one with.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of using this line before `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Basically, in your original code, you declared a trailing slash, so it requires a trailing slash